# How does count(nodes(p)) work in Cypher, Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for an explanation of how this works and why doesn't return the number of nodes in a path. Suppose I matched a path p. Now:

```
WITH p, count(nodes(p)) AS L1 RETURN L1
```

returns 1.

When this is clear, how do I count paths nodes properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`count()` is an **aggregate function**. When using any aggregate function, result rows will be grouped by whatever is included in the RETURN clause and **not** an aggregate function. In this case, result rows will be grouped by `p` and the return value will be count(nodes(p)).

`nodes(p)` returns **an array** of nodes, so `count(nodes(p))` will return the count of arrays and will always equal `1`.

In order return the amount of nodes in the path you should use `size(nodes(p))`.

If you're just interested in the length of a path and not particularly in the nodes that are included in it, I would **encourage you to use `length(p)`**. This will return the length in rels for a given path, without having to manipulate/access the nodes.

Comment: "length in rels" is an important qualification - it used to trip me up constantly that length is length in rels, it's *not* the number of nodes in the path, which is always one more.

Comment: You say `result rows will be grouped by whatever is included in the RETURN clause` but then you say `In this case, result rows will be grouped by p`. You contradict yourself